# CoreText - how to center text within frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to center CoreText, and the best example I found was in this [blog post](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/coretext-set-text-font-and-alignment-to-cfattributedstring.html). However, I was working with NSAttributedString, and although the CFMutableAttributedStringReference should [be toll-free bridged](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/coretext-set-text-font-and-alignment-to-cfattributedstring.html) to NSMutableAttributedString, this doesn't seem to work any bridging magic when I try to introduce the following in my `drawRect` method:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                  initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", self.currentNum, self.units]]; //2


//    set paragraph style attribute
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attString, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle);

//    set font attribute
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attString, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTFontAttributeName, font);
```

In particular, I am getting the same build error for both of the last two lines:

```
Incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type 'NSMutableAttributedString'__strong to a CF function expecting 'CFMutableAttributedStringRef' (aka 'struct __CFAttributedString *') type.
```

I get that toll-free bridging doesn't have to go backwards, but then how can I set the alignment of my NSMutableAttributedString to center it in the provided frame? I don't know the text or size of the text in advance, so I need to be able to center it so it looks alright in a variety of sizes.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you blog post link refer to apple documentation please edit

Comment: @MejdiLassidi thanks for taking a look and sorry about that. I corrected the link.

Comment: Now your documentation link refers to the blog post.

Comment: What is paragraphStyle?

Comment: @Willeke in that case there is some bug in the platform. I linked each link separately, I don't know why they are combined.

Comment: @ElTomato it's a paragraphstyle type. You can see the full code if you go to the blog link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast toll free bridged types as documented in [Casting and Object Lifetime Semantics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677-SW2).

Quote:

> Through toll-free bridging, in a method where you see for example an NSLocale * parameter, you can pass a CFLocaleRef, and in a function where you see a CFLocaleRef parameter, you can pass an NSLocale instance. You also have to provide other information for the compiler: first, you have to cast one type to the other; in addition, you may have to indicate the object lifetime semantics.

Example:

`CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)attString, …`

Alternatively you can use NSMutableAttributedString's methods to add attributes.